# Daterangepicker requires underscore to be loaded

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, date-range, daterangepicker

I'm trying to run `daterangepicker()` on a website but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
<input class="daterangepicker-field">

$(".daterangepicker-field").daterangepicker({
    forceUpdate: true,
    callback: function(startDate, endDate, period){
        var title = startDate.format('L') + ' – ' + endDate.format('L');
        $(this).val(title);
    }
 });
```

This doesn't work on my input and it says that `daterangepicker requires underscore to be loaded`

Comment: Did you include all the required dependencies? Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/34eq7jxx/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG I'm not using that one from bootstrap. And yes all the dependencies are included.

Comment: Ok, in that case create a [mcve].

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/sensortower/daterangepicker/releases added in my gruntfile and I just call it with the jQuery example I gave. Do you think there's anything else I need to do?

Comment: My bad! I resolved this. thanks @ChrisG